# Uncaught Error: A valid React element (or null) must be returned

Tags: reactjs

i keep getting this error and every thing i have done seems good
can anyone help me out ? `

```
    var React = require('react');
    var ListItem = require('./ListItem.jsx');

    var List = React.createClass({
      render : function () {
        var createItem = function(text, index){
          return <ListItem key={index + text} text= {text} />;
        };
        return (<ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>);
      }
    });
    module.exports = List ;

`


i even put () after return , nothing happend.

here is my other snippets :

    var React = require('react');
var ListItem = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return
    (
      <li>
        <h4>
          {this.props.text}
        </h4>
      </li>
    );
  }
});
module.exports = ListItem;
```

so im getting this error more than you think . i wanna know why because im new in this react thing

Comment: can you show `ListItem` component ?

Comment: here it is @MayankShukla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in this line:

```
return
(
...
)
```

It will be treated as `return;` and it will not `return` any thing.

One more thing initially `items` can be `null` or `undefined`, so you need to put check on that before using `map`:

```
return (<ul>{Array.isArray(this.props.items) ? this.props.items.map(createItem) : null}</ul>);
```

Use this:

```js
var List = React.createClass({
   render : function () {
      var createItem = function(text, index){
         return <ListItem key={index + text} text= {text} />;
      };
      return (<ul>{Array.isArray(this.props.items) ? this.props.items.map(createItem) : null}</ul>);
    }
});

var ListItem = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return(
      <li>
        <h4>
          {this.props.text}
        </h4>
      </li>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<List items={[1,2,3,4]}/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that `this.props.items` is **empty** or **undefined** upon the first time render is called

Therefor you should test it first.

```
var React = require('react');
var ListItem = require('./ListItem.jsx');

var List = React.createClass({
    mapItems: function() {
       if(this.props.items) {
         return this.props.items.map(function(text, index) {
            return <ListItem key={index + text} text= {text} />;
         })
       }
       //EDIT 1
       else {
           return <span>Empty list</span>;
       }
    },
    render : function () {
        return <ul>{ this.mapItems() }</ul>;
    }
});
module.exports = List ;
```

ListItem:

```
var React = require('react');
var ListItem = React.createClass({
      render : function() {
        return <li>
                  <h4>
                    {this.props.text}
                  </h4>
               </li>
      }
});
module.exports = ListItem;
```

**EDIT**

On a **return** statement, the first character after **return** should be on the same line.
[Working JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/74068/)

Comment: i did that now im just getting a blank page without no response :/  @Tikkes

Comment: seems like it crashes on the else statement :   return (<ul>{ this.mapItems() }</ul>); @Tikkes

Comment: Yes so your `this.props.items` are actually empty. You could put an else in place to have a response nonetheless. See edit. --- If it crashes on that line, what is the error message? (in detail please)

Comment: first of all thanks for response . when it passes the if statement it will actually returns nothing , i mean it's blank unless i change the else statement then every time i submit anything it will show me the exact thing i put in else statement ... hope it's clear @Tikkes

Comment: Based on @Reden Sanchez response, I found that your return on `ListItem` is wrong. It should start on the same line. See [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/74068/) - Credit to Reden Sanchez. So to be short: it is "return <li>........", no enter before the first next character. This too goes for the `List` component

Comment: thnx a lot saved my day @Tikkes